# Using Mockito w/o Maven

Tags: java, maven, jar, download, mockito

I am making a small java library to parse URI parameters. I implemented it, and am in the process of making JUnit tests for it. I realized that I needed to use a mocking framework, and I did some research and chose Mockito. But since I am not using Maven or Gradle, I do not know how to include the Mockito jar files in my Eclipse project. Reading the documentation, I found that I need to use the Mockito-all jar file, instead of the Mockito-core jar file, but the Mockito-all release has been discontinued since v2.

I looked at Mockito-core's pom file, and found that it depended on other libraries. Is the only way for me to be able to use Mockito to track down all the dependencies of Mockito-core, and dependencies of those dependencies, and to download all those jar files? Or is there a simple way for me to get a single jar file for the latest version of Mockito?

### Edit

I know:

- how to import jar files into eclipse
- how to add user libraries into a project

I don't know:

- which mockito jar(s) to download
- where to get those jar(s) from

Comment: Your problem seems to be: "I am not using Maven or Gradle". Why not? You can still distribute your library, presumably without their unit tests, and it'd be useful for users of the library without them needing to do anything with Maven or Gradle, if they choose to do so. (In which case: _Why not?_ would again be a good question, but alas.)

Answer (score 2):

- download mockito jar(s)

in eclipse

- create a [*user library*](https://www.heise.de/forum/heise-online/Hardware/Speicher/USB-Sticks-Achtung-die-tatsaechliche-Kapazitaet/posting-24522991/show/)
- add the  *user library* to your projects classpath

> What jar(s)? I know how to add them in eclipse, but I don't know where to download the jars from. I will clarify in the question – vikarjramun

http://repo1.maven.org/maven2/org/mockito/mockito-core/2.7.22/
http://search.maven.org/#search%7Cga%7C1%7Cbyte-buddy
http://search.maven.org/#search|ga|1|byte-buddy-agent
http://search.maven.org/#search|ga|1|objenesis

Comment: I see you answered my question, but I am hoping some one else has a better answer that allows use of only a single jar. I guess this is why I should be using maven

Comment: Side note: I see that maven has a jar file, sources jar file, and javadoc jar file. Is there a jar with all of these?

Comment: Why would you need all of these for your use?

Comment: @SanderVerhagen *"Why would you need all of these for your use?"* These are the dependencies defined in mockitos POM for version 2.7.22.

Comment: I was talking about the sources and Javadoc JARs. The real solution here is to use Maven or Gradle (or Ant or Ivy, if you really have to), so that your IDE can pull in these derived artifacts as needed, and you don't need to worry about them. I've not heard any arguments for not using Maven or Gradle. While it's someone's right to go that way, we should advise against it. Even when using Maven for development of the library (as with using Mockito), you can still distribute the result as JAR (without POM, test code, or Mockito), as there's apparently no compile or runtime dependencies involved.